# Инсталлятор Visual Studio не может скачать файл

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cocos2d

При попытке установить в `Visual Studio` пакет с `Cocos2d`, возникает данная ошибка:

> После нескольких попыток (девять) не удалось скачать следующий файл:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=854219
>
> Выберите команду "Продолжить", чтобы установить Visual Studio, не
> скачивая этот файл. Из-за этого могут возникнуть проблемы на других
> этапах установки.
>
> Выберите команду "Повторить", чтобы попытаться скачать файл еще раз.
>
> Выберите команду "Отмена", чтобы отменить установку Visual Studio.
>
> [Помощь в установке за брандмауэром или
> прокси-сервером.](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=872312)

Каким образом можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Прямая ссылка на файл

Легко получается переходом по ссылке из вопроса:
https://digitalocean.cocos2d-x.org/CocosCreator/v1.5.2/CocosCreator_v1.5.2-1_2017070701_setup.exe

## Проблема:

IP-адрес сайта (но не сам сайт) заблокирован РКН:

[image: Cкриншот блокировки по IP]

[image: Скриншот отсутствия блокировки по домену]

## Возможное решение:

1. Скачиваешь файл любым доступным способом
2. Устанавливаешь [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), который теперь выпускается как [Fiddler Classic](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic).
3. В настройках разрешаешь перехват и расшифровку https-трафика
4. Включаешь autoresponder, при этом выставляешь unmatched requests pass through

   [image: Скриншот Fiddler'а]
5. В папке с файлом запускаешь http-server
6. Через браузер скачиваешь файл с localhost'а
7. В Fiddler'е перетаскиваешь строчку со скачиванием файла в autoresponder
8. Тыкаешь строчку в autoresponder'е и в rule editor меняешь url на тот, который хочет инсталлятор VS
9. В инсталляторе VS жмёшь Повторить, ответ подменяется фиддлером, инсталлятор получает желаемый файл и всё хорошо ставится

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать по 5 пункту. Как запустить http-сервер?

Comment: @Redis, как угодно. Если есть nodejs, то вот этот пойдёт: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server. Если нет,можно с IIS поиграться, или с .net core. Или ещё что-нибудь нарыть.